# Is there an NPER or financial function library available that supports NPER functions?

Tags: java, android, financial

I've been scouring the internet for the better part of two days looking for a JAVA financial library that has functions similar to Excel's, particularly NPER.    the closest thing I've come to is the one here:[NPER formula](http://doc.optadata.com/en/dokumentation/application/expression/functions/financial.html), except when I type that into a solver here:[math calculator](http://www.mathway.com/answer.aspx?p=calg?p=%28SMB20%28%2880%2a%281%20.13%2a1%29%20%28-1SMB10%28.13%29%29%2a1%29SMB10%28%283000%2a.13%2080%29%2a%281%20.13%2a0%29%29%29SMB10SMB20%281%20.13%29%29%2a100?p=2?p=?p=?p=?p=?p=0?p=?p=0?p=?p=)  using the following:

```
((√((80*(1+.13*1)+(-1/.13)*0)/((3000*.13+80)*(1+.13*1)))/√(1+.13)))*100
```

I get a different number than what excel gives me.  The values I'm using are 3000$ owed, 13% interest, 80$ monthly payment.   Excel and calculators online indicate 49 months (48.3 rounded up), but that formula gives me 39.4 months.   Does anyone know of a java library I can implement in my code to perform calculations like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The arithmetic errors are probably because Java is using Integer math. Integer math completely disregards the decimal point by rounding down the value after each operation.  Consider the following code:

```
int xInt = 5;
int yInt = (xInt/2) * 3;

double xDouble = 5;
double yDouble = (xDouble/2) * 3;
```

The resulting values of `yInt` and `yDouble` are different. `yInt` is 6 while `yDouble` is 7.5.

In your code you should convert the integer values to doubles or floats by appending decimal places. like this:

```
double val1 = (5/2)*3; // this equals 6, Don't do this
double val2 = (5.0/2.0)*3.0 // this equals 7.5, instead do this
```

Comment: i haven't done anything in java yet, I'm using a solver online and entering in the equation to match the formula that was provided in the other link.   I may attempt to programmatically do the equation, but I'd like to make sure that I have the correct formula that matches what online financial calculators show.  Having a Java library that has an NPER function would save me a huge amount of effort in doing this.

Comment: Looks like this works: http://www.ehow.com/how_2154015_calculate-term-investment-using-microsoft.html  I just compared the results against the 2 online calculators and they match